# Why is my filter page not finding results within the database?

Tags: php, html, sql, search, filter

I am in the process of creating a filter page that should return a table of results dependent upon the selection chose from a drop down list. 
I have generated the code for this and no errors are found. However, no results show up despite them being present in the database.

Am I missing something?
Please let me know if any further information is required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');

$search_output= "";

$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"assessment_centre_app");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {

$Name_FK = $_POST['Name_FK'];

$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * 
                                    FROM scores 
                                        WHERE 'Name_FK' = {'$Name_FK'}");

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);   

    if($count > 1) {
        $search_output .="$count results for $searchquery";         
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $Candidate_Name_FK = $row["Candidate_Name_FK"];
            $search_output .="Item ID: $Candidate_Name_FK <br />";
                }
    } else {
        $search_output= "0 results found";

        }
    } 
    ?>      





<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/scoresheet/scoresheetfilter.php" method="POST">

            <label> Assessment Day Name </label>                    
            <select name = "Name_FK">
            <?php
            $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM scores");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
            ?>
            <option>
            <?php echo $row["Name_FK"];  ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input name ="myBtn" id="submit" type="submit" >            
            <br>
        </form>

<div>
<?php echo $search_output;
 ?>         
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try putting the '' outside of the {}? `'{$Name_FK}'`

Comment: `'Name_FK'` should be in backticks, not quotes, or nothing. Quotes are for strings. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Hi Lewis, thanks for your advice. I gave this a go and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have not had any luck with applying back ticks either unfortunately. This is just being delivered as a proof of concept, security will be covered in the full version.

Comment: update this line with: `$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * 
                                    FROM scores 
                                        WHERE Name_FK = '$Name_FK'");`

Comment: Hi Murtaza. I have made this update and still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out if it still does not display anything the check the variable used to call this other one's

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors','1');

   $search_output= "";

 $link= new mysqli("localhost", "user_name", "password", "database");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {

    $Name_FK = $_POST['Name_FK'];

       $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE Name_FK='$Name_FK'";

      $query = mysqli_query($linnk, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

     $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);   

 if($count > 1) {
    $search_output .="$count results for $searchquery";         
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $Candidate_Name_FK = $row["Candidate_Name_FK"];
        $search_output .="Item ID: $Candidate_Name_FK <br />";

        echo $search_output; //echo to check result
            }
} else {
    $search_output= "0 results found";
    echo $search_output; //echo to check result
    }
} 
?>
```

Now edited

variable 
     $searchquery

not created

Comment: Hi JBoy, no luck unfortunately. Anything else you would be able to advise?

Comment: but you are sure you posted a form to this page because it using POST

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this? Can you please explain?

Comment: I have edited the above code to make there no errors. but make sure a form is submited to this page else it wont work. If you are still having any doubt with code remove the         if(isset['submit']{         to see if the script is showing any error.